# Processing template at index.html

Tags: html-framework-7

- Framework7 Version: 1.6.0
- Platform and Target: Hybrid Mobile App/Android.

I tried to get understanding how to work with templates at index.page, but I failed.

There is my code

index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="views">
    <div class="view view-main">
        <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <div class="page-content">
                <p>Hello, my name is {{name}} and i am {{age}} years old</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
...
<!-- Path to your app js-->
...
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js is

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    template7Pages: true,
    precompileTemplates: true,
    template7Data: {
        index: {
            name: 'John Doe',
            age: 38,
            company: 'Apple',
            position: 'Developer'
        }
    }
});

var $$ = Dom7;
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Because we use fixed-through navbar we can enable dynamic navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true
});
```

And I have

```
Hello, my name is {{name}} and i am {{age}} years old
```

I found out (I don't remember where) that tempates are not processing at index.html and the following solution solves this issue.

1. Move template's content to external file
2. Load content of external file to view on page load

My code was changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="views">
    <div class="view view-main">
        <div class="pages navbar-fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
...
<!-- Path to your app js-->
...
</body>
</html>
```

items.html

```
<div data-page="items" class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
        <p>Hello, my name is {{name}} and i am {{age}} years old</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

my app.js

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    template7Pages: true,
    precompileTemplates: true,
    template7Data: {
        items: {
            name: 'John Doe',
            age: 38,
            company: 'Apple',
            position: 'Developer'
        }
    }
});

var $$ = Dom7;

var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    // Because we use fixed-through navbar we can enable dynamic navbar
    dynamicNavbar: true
});

mainView.router.loadPage('items.html');
```

And I have

```
Hello, my name is and i am years old
```

How right to include template to index.html?

Comment: It needs to use the following:

``` 
template7Data: {
        'url:items.html': function () {
            return {items: getItems()};
        }
    }
```